# Processing using ControlP5 listbox

Tags: listbox, processing, indexoutofboundsexception

I encountered really a strange problem with using a ControlP5 ListBox in my program. I found an example of ListBox use from the official page of ControlP5 library: http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/examples/controllers/ControlP5listBox/ControlP5listBox.pde I did some simple changes like changing listbox width and height, setting different colors. The main difference consist in the fact I'm using an arrayList of Strings to populate listbox. Here is the complete code for this scetch:

```
import javax.swing.*;
PFrame f;
public class PFrame extends JFrame {
  public SecondApplet s;
  public PFrame(int width, int height,ArrayList<String> companiesTxt) {
    setBounds(100, 100, width, height);
    s = new SecondApplet(companiesTxt);
    add(s);
    s.init();
    show();
  }
}
public class SecondApplet extends PApplet {
  ArrayList<String> companiesText;

ControlP5 cp5;

ListBox l;

ControlWindow controlWindow;
  SecondApplet(ArrayList<String> cmpTxt){
    companiesText = cmpTxt;
  }
  void setup(){
    size(400, 720);
    ControlP5.printPublicMethodsFor(ListBox.class);
    cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
    l = cp5.addListBox("myList")
         .setPosition(0, 0)
         .setSize(382, 720)
         .setItemHeight(18)
         .setBarHeight(18)
         .setColorBackground(color(243, 45,98))
         .setColorActive(color(0))
         .setColorForeground(color(255, 100,0))
         ;

  l.captionLabel().toUpperCase(true);
  l.captionLabel().set("Companies");
  l.captionLabel().setColor(0xffff0000);
  l.captionLabel().style().marginTop = 3;
  l.valueLabel().style().marginTop = 3;

  for (int i=0;i != companiesText.size();i++) {

    ListBoxItem lbi = l.addItem(companiesText.get(i), i);
    lbi.setColorBackground(color(243, 45,98));


  }
}

  void draw(){

  } 
}
```

When I try to scroll this listbox, I get an exception:

```
     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8217
at controlP5.BitFont.getGlyph(Unknown Source)
at processing.core.PGraphics.textCharImpl(PGraphics.java:4681)
at processing.core.PGraphics.textLineImpl(PGraphics.java:4669)
at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.textLineImpl(PGraphicsJava2D.java:1787)
at processing.core.PGraphics.textLineAlignImpl(PGraphics.java:4659)
at processing.core.PGraphics.text(PGraphics.java:4356)
at processing.core.PGraphics.text(PGraphics.java:4307)
at processing.core.PApplet.text(PApplet.java:13183)
at controlP5.ControlFont.draw(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.Label.draw(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.Label$SinglelineLabel.draw(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.Label.draw(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.Button$ButtonView.display(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.Button$ButtonView.display(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.Controller.draw(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.ControllerGroup.drawControllers(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.ControllerGroup.draw(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.ControllerGroup.drawControllers(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.ControllerGroup.draw(Unknown Source)
at controlP5.ControlWindow.draw(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at processing.core.PApplet$RegisteredMethods.handle(PApplet.java:1236)
at processing.core.PApplet$RegisteredMethods.handle(PApplet.java:1229)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleMethods(PApplet.java:1423)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2401)
at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm almost desperate because I do not understand what can be wrong in this case? Please, can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: not strictly related, but more of a code organisational question: why is your `draw()` function empty? Making sure `setup` contains your setup, and `draw` the actual draw code is a reasonable first step in ruling out odd behaviour due to drawing too early (don't draw in setup, for instance)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I understand your question but I followed the example from the official website. The main problem consists in the fact that I do not understand why I have index of bounds exception.

Comment: what's in `companiesText`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It's Array Of strings. I resolved the problem and will  post solution right now.

Comment: just remember to look at your posts after you post them - the formating for the code in your answer needs fixing. On a content note: if possible, never use ascii, it's a great way to introduce bugs. Where you have the option, stick with utf8, or utf16 if utf8 is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved. I was using some strings that are not aschii characters. GetGlyph function looks like this:

```
public Glyph getGlyph(char c) {
   return glyphs[(int) (c)];
}
```

So, when you want to use a listbox convert characters to aschii:

```
 for (int i=0;i < companiesText.size();i++) {
      try{
          ListBoxItem lbi = l.addItem(newString(companiesText.get(i).getBytes("US-ASCII"),"US-ASCII"), i);
          lbi.setColorBackground(color(243, 45,98));
      }catch(Exception e){
      }
 }
```